# How can I get all my friends and the current user posts in a Firebase Real Time Database Query?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**UPDATE1: I still working on it but I can't solve it, maybe restructuring the database? I'll continue thinking but if someone has an idea it will be great to hear**

Well I'm trying to get all current users friends and his own posts in a firebase query but I can't get them, always I tryed I only get one friend posts because the others are overwritten. Let me show you how my data base (JSON) is structured and how I want to display the post in the Android project Activity.

```
UserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
PostRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Post");

...
```

```
...
 UserRef.child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                {

                    if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("Friends")){
                        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.child("Friends").getChildren()){
                            friendsID = ds.getKey(); //String with friendsID
                            DisplayAllUserPosts();
                        }
                    }...
```

```
...
  private void DisplayAllUserPosts() {

        Query SortPost = PostRef.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(friendsID);

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Posts> options=new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Posts>().setQuery(SortPost,Posts.class).build(); \\Posts class is just for getting data base Post nodes elements
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, PostsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, PostsViewHolder>(options) {...
```

My Firebase Real Time Database is structured like this:

```
{
"Post" : {
    "10-04-201918:32:09" : {
      "counter" : 0,
      "date" : "10-04-2019",
      "fullname" : "Xuban Illarramendi",
      "postimage" : "XXXX",
      "profileimage" : "XXXX",
      "status" : "",
      "time" : "18:32:09",
      "uid" : "FP1YJnlJBpfU5aSZlSAErLODWZl2"
    },
    "10-04-201921:10:06" : {
      "counter" : 0,
      "date" : "10-04-2019",
      "fullname" : "Ander Lopez",
      "postimage" : "XXXX",
      "profileimage" : "XXXX",
      "status" : "",
      "time" : "21:10:06",
      "uid" : "8wXFsw1pBRYXBVtChqY1Kqi14dy1"
    }
  },
  "Users" : {
    "8wXFsw1pBRYXBVtChqY1Kqi14dy1" : {
      "Friends" : {
        "FP1YJnlJBpfU5aSZlSAErLODWZl2" : {
          "date" : "10-04-2019"
        },
        "sWQGtchFE1fvuSIfPb42ZIWVkbU2" : {
          "date" : "10-04-2019"
        }
      },
      "country" : "Spain",
      "dob" : "none",
      "fullname" : "Ander Lopez",
      "gender" : "none",
      "profileimage" : "XXXX",
      "relationshipstatus" : "none",
      "status" : "",
      "username" : "anderlopz"
    },
    "FP1YJnlJBpfU5aSZlSAErLODWZl2" : {
      "Friends" : {
        "8wXFsw1pBRYXBVtChqY1Kqi14dy1" : {
          "date" : "10-04-2019"
        },
        "sWQGtchFE1fvuSIfPb42ZIWVkbU2" : {
          "date" : "10-04-2019"
        }
      },
      "country" : "Spain",
      "dob" : "none",
      "fullname" : "Xuban Illarramendi",
      "gender" : "none",
      "profileimage" : "XXXX",
      "relationshipstatus" : "none",
      "status" : "",
      "username" : "xuban"
    },
    "sWQGtchFE1fvuSIfPb42ZIWVkbU2" : {
      "Friends" : {
        "8wXFsw1pBRYXBVtChqY1Kqi14dy1" : {
          "date" : "10-04-2019"
        },
        "FP1YJnlJBpfU5aSZlSAErLODWZl2" : {
          "date" : "10-04-2019"
        }
      },
      "country" : "Spain",
      "dob" : "none",
      "fullname" : "Unai Lopez",
      "gender" : "none",
      "profileimage" : "XXXX",
      "relationshipstatus" : "none",
      "status" : "",
      "username" : "unailopz"
    }
  }
}
```

So my real problem is that he displays only the last friend posts, how can I make a query that contains all my friendsID without overwritting the previous friendsID?

Comment: I think your call to `DisplayAllUserPosts()` should be after the for loop, not inside it.

Comment: Please replace the schematic diagram of your data with a snippet of the actual relevant JSON (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Have you solved the issue? Please reponde with @.

Comment: @AlexMamo no I didn't I try writting the method call after the for loop like they said before but still doing the same thing

Comment: @AnderLopez What is happening when you are calling `DisplayAllUserPosts()` outside the loop?

Comment: @AlexMamo when I call the method the value of the friendsID is the last value he takes for that loop so is almost the same thing that was happening with the call inside